# Is there a way we can display Outlook Add In Notification based on certain validation on an Outlook Android App

Tags: android, outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing an Outlook Add In, have added support for Mobile [] as well, but for some reason "Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.addAsync" doesn't seem to work on android. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you use a native app or web browser on Android?

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you share the snippet which you were using for this.

Comment: var id = $("#notificationId").val();
var details =
  {
    type: "informationalMessage",
    message: "Non-persistent informational notification message with id = " + id,
    icon: "icon1",
    persistent: false
  };
Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.addAsync(id, details, handleResult);

This doesnt work on Android App

Comment: I use native android app from google play store

Comment: Any update on this

Comment: I tried the following and it's working on Android.

var nonpersistent_infobar_id = "my_nonpersistent_infobar_id_00"; 
Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.addAsync( nonpersistent_infobar_id, 
{ 
type: "informationalMessage", message: "Non-persistent informational infobar with id = " + nonpersistent_infobar_id, 
icon: "icon1", 
persistent: false } 
); 

If you continue to see this problem, please share a repro video of the same to help us investigate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add-ins aren't supported in Outlook on Android, on iOS, and modern mobile web with on-premises Exchange accounts. Add-ins don't work in modern Outlook on the web on iPhone and Android smartphones. For information about supported devices, see [Requirements for running Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/requirements-for-running-office-add-ins#client-requirements-non-windows-smartphone-and-tablet).

Comment: I'm using Outlook for Android, add in works but only the notifications do not work.